# Transform point cloud's coordinates to another coordinates in Point Cloud Library, which makes the ground plane as the X-O-Y plane?

Tags: c++, kinect, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud from kinect fusion and use Point Cloud Library to segment the ground plane(a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0) successfully(I got the a,b,c,d in pcl::ModelCoefficients of the ground plane). Now I need to transform the Cartesian coordinates to new Cartesian coordinates that makes the ground plane became the X-O-Y plane(0*x+0*y+z=0). 
I guess I can do it by this API(but I don't know how):
http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__common.html#transformPointCloud

**My Answer**:
Look at this PCL api:http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.2/a02405.html#ga4375e99ec2ae368eec9379f506568611

I successfully solved this problem!

Comment: For the sake of public benefit, you should write a complete answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: the link you provided doesnt work, could you provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

I can't open the link to your API but guess you can transform you plane using simple transformations:

1. you should add to all your points vector {a * d, b * d, c * d} -
   that moves your points to plane ax + by + cz = 0
2. then you should find rotation matrix around axis [{a, b, c} cross
   {0, 0, 1}] on angle [{a, b, c} dot {0, 0, 1}] and transform your
   points by this matrix
   http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToMatrix- here you can see how to find the rotation matrix from axis and angle

Answer (score 0):

This function requires camera pose, which is a 4x4 matrix, of the form

```
| R   t |
| 0   1 |
```

Here, R is 3x3 rotation matrix, t is a 3x1 translation vector, 0 - is a 1x3 vector of zeros, and 1 is a unity (scalar).

You should design this matrix in such a way, that Z axis in a new coordinate system will be collinear to the normal vector of your plane. New X and Y axes are arbitrary, the only restriction is that they must form orthogonal basis.

[This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476311) explains how to derive matrix R.

Answer (score -1):

Now, I meet this question. I want to project point cloud to XY plane,YZ plane, and XZ plane. Finally, the answer be found in this page:
https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/project_inliers.html?highlight=ModelCoefficients:

In this tutorial we will learn how to project points onto a parametric model (e.g., plane, sphere, etc). The parametric model is given through a set of coefficients – in the case of a plane, through its equation: ax + by + cz + d = 0.
Avoid the page missing, copy the code as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/filters/project_inliers.h>

int
 main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_projected (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Fill in the cloud data
  //We then create the point cloud structure, fill in the respective values,        and display the content on screen.
  cloud->width  = 5;
  cloud->height = 1;
  cloud->points.resize (cloud->width * cloud->height);

  for (auto& point: *cloud)
  {
    point.x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    point.y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    point.z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
  }

  std::cerr << "Cloud before projection: " << std::endl;
  for (const auto& point: *cloud)
    std::cerr << "    " << point.x << " "
                        << point.y << " "
                        << point.z << std::endl;

  // Create a set of planar coefficients with X=Y=0,Z=1
  //We fill in the ModelCoefficients values. In this case, we use a plane model, with ax+by+cz+d=0, where a=b=d=0, and c=1, or said differently, the X-Y plane.
  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
  coefficients->values.resize (4);
  coefficients->values[0] = coefficients->values[1] = 0;
  coefficients->values[2] = 1.0;
  coefficients->values[3] = 0;

  // Create the filtering object
  //We create the ProjectInliers object and use the ModelCoefficients defined above as the model to project onto.
  pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZ> proj;
  proj.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  proj.setInputCloud (cloud);
  proj.setModelCoefficients (coefficients);
  proj.filter (*cloud_projected);

  std::cerr << "Cloud after projection: " << std::endl;
  for (const auto& point: *cloud_projected)
    std::cerr << "    " << point.x << " "
                        << point.y << " "
                        << point.z << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

The code above from PCL website.