# Visualize pointcloud

Tags: opencv, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have 3D points from gpu::reprojectImageTo3D on a found disparity image. I would now like to display this pointcloud.

How do I Convert the found pointcloud from `OpenCV` to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` ?

I do not need to publish the pointcloud this is only for debug visualization. Could it be possible to display it as is done with images from the node? e.g. using `pcl`? This would be optimal since my device may not perform well with `RViz` (based on readings online).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is to do like this, and just iterate through the `cv::mat` and insert in the `pcl` to convert to msg, since I have not found anything that does directly.

```c++
#include <ros/ros.h>
// point cloud headers
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
//Header which contain PCL to ROS and ROS to PCL conversion functions
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
//sensor_msgs header for point cloud2
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "pcl_create");
    ROS_INFO("Started PCL publishing node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    //Creating publisher object for point cloud
    ros::Publisher pcl_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("pcl_output", 1);
    //Creating a cloud object
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    //Creating a sensor_msg of point cloud
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
    //Insert cloud data
    cloud.width  = 50000;
    cloud.height = 2;
    cloud.points.resize(cloud.width * cloud.height);
    //Insert random points on the clouds
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); ++i)
    {
        cloud.points[i].x = 512 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud.points[i].y = 512 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud.points[i].z = 512 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }
    //Convert the cloud to ROS message
    pcl::toROSMsg(cloud, output);
    output.header.frame_id = "point_cloud";
    ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        //publishing point cloud data
        pcl_pub.publish(output);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code snippet was found at [apprize](http://apprize.info/programming/ros/9.html).